# MySql Left Join Returns all the match rows except the very first match row

Tags: mysql, join

Hello guys I have this problem The tables are:

```
      images: 

id || path_id  || name
1       1         example1.jpg
2       1         example2.jpg
3       1         example3.jpg
4       2         example4.jpg

      path:

id || folder_path
1      "./...."
2      "./...."
```

The query is this:

```
$query="SELECT images.name,path.folder_path FROM images 
        LEFT JOIN 
        path ON path.id=images.path_id 
        WHERE path.id=?";
```

Lets say the `?` is `1`. This will return every picture except the very first that is matching `example1.jpg`. If i put the `example2.jpg` as the very first row then it will skip `example2.jpg` and it will give me the `example1.jpg`. Why?? What I want is all the pics with specific path_id + the folder_path of this specific id.
The whole query.

```
 $query="SELECT images.name,path.folder_path FROM images 
        LEFT JOIN 
        path ON path.id=images.path_id 
        WHERE path.id=?";
        if($stmt= $mysqli->prepare($query))
        {
                for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
                {
                    $bind_param= $result[$i];
                    /*bind parameters*/
                    $stmt->bind_param("s",$bind_param);
                    /* execute query */
                    $stmt->execute();

                    /* bind result variables */
                    $stmt->bind_result($images,$path); 
                    $stmt->fetch();
                }
                $i=0;
               while($stmt->fetch()){
                    printf("%d) %s PATH:%s \n",$i,$images,$path);
                    $i++;
               }
                $stmt->close();.
```

The $result is the id=1. And when I try to printf the data it print only 2 of the 3 images I expect and the correct folder_path.

Comment: Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: I want: example1.jpg ,  example2.jpg, example3.jpg +  "./...." (of id=1)
I get: example2.jpg, example3.jpg +  "./...." (of id=1)

Comment: change the WHERE to **WHERE image.id=?";**

Comment: the same problem... It is just cutting the first column of table images that is matching the where

Comment: Your original query is correct (I think).  THe problem (I think) is in your application.  Pls, next time try to make an effort to write in a clearer way

Comment: Your query is completely fine, q.v. [this demo](http://rextester.com/VCEQU66338).

Comment: NO YOUR QUERY IS NOT FINE. Its got nothing to do with the problem you describe but `LEFT JOIN 
        path ON path.id=images.path_id 
        WHERE path.id=?` is a really bad query. The predicate excludes the extra rows added by an outer join. The query should use an inner join.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thanks for replying . I will try later to make the query more efficient but for now that its working I will let it as it is. Thank you guys

Comment: The problem you describe may have something to do with the fact that you are not assigning a value to $result in the PHP code above - but must be assigning a value elsewhere to get the result meaning there are more bugs in the code we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Problem was this line inside the loop, I tried yesterday and i didn't see it was there this day.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
....
....
$stmt->fetch(); /* <--- Problem */
}
```

As documentary saying "Note that all columns must be bound by the application before calling mysqli_stmt_fetch()".
So that means I will fetch the data after the loop is done and not simultaneously.